# What regular expression do I use to detect a user accessing website with IE8?

Tags: regex, internet-explorer-8

We are using the Squiz CMS to update a website. We want to update the menu with Mega Menu from Codyhouse but it won't work on IE8.

I want to run a browser detection on the system (sniffer) and change some of the CMS code depending if the user is accessing the website through IE8 browser. I have to use RegEx as that is what the system uses.

I am looking everywhere for the expression that can detect an IE8 browser, e.g.

```
MSIE8
```

But it will now work. Does anyone out there happen to know the RegEx for IE8?

**EDIT:** have investigated and its simply not possible to use PHP. In the end I used pattern of MSIE which targeted IE 8,9 and 10 - best I could do.

Comment: Depending on your language, there should be a library that extracts the browser type from the User-Agent reliably.

Comment: Using Squiz Matrix CMS. It uses a language similar to XML for creating 'design files' but what drives it is PHP and mySQL. I would love to get my hands on that library...

Comment: There's quite a few for PHP. Even a built-in function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: Third party library: https://github.com/donatj/PhpUserAgent

Comment: Thanks for the php tips but I need to investigate further. System is proprietary based and I don't think that they have/allow exposing the php code.

Answer (score 1):

conditional comments and conditional compilation are your friends
use conditional comments to detect < ie11
use conditional compilation to detect all ie versions
implement like so:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script src="ie8-library.js"></script>
<p>This Content Will only Be Visible in IE8.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Are you talking about these guys here? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - because I gave that a shot and it just did not work out with the CMS (mySource Matrix) code we use to generate menus with. In the end I targeted 'MSIE' which I have outlined in my update.

Comment: that comment makes me think a few things may be happening, but yes, those are conditional comments. i'll update my answer to show you

Comment: BTW, I have used conditional comments heaps in the past to inject in specific IE styles and JS files but this system/framework I am working within just 'cuts me up'...